# Use user input as function arguments in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the users inputs in e1, e2, e3, e4 as class arguments for the class Data(). I tried creating a function get_args() but it just returns empty stings since action by the user has to be taken to actually show the inputs. What is the best way of taking user input and using them as funtion arguments?

```
d = Data()




import tkinter as tk
from hist import Data

def quit(root):
    root.destroy()

#def get_args():
    #return e1.get(), e2.get(),e3.get(), e4.get()

def show_entry_fields():
    print("Ticker: %s\nStart Date: %s\nEnd Date: %s\nBasis: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get(),e3.get(),e4.get()))


root = tk.Tk()



tk.Label(root, text="Ticker").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Start Date").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="End Date").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Basis").grid(row=3)

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e3 = tk.Entry(root)
e4 = tk.Entry(root)


e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)



#Data = Data(get_args())
#Ticker = d.get_histocial_prices()

tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)


tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
#tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=Ticker).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When do you want the `Data` instance to be created? How do you decide when the Entry fields have suitable data in them for creating the instance?

Comment: I guess I would like to press a button when I have decided that the entries have suitable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variables as `global` in `get_args()` function as:

```
import tkinter as tk
from hist import Data

def get_args():
    global ticker, start_date, end_date, basics

    ticker = e1.get()
    start_date = e2.get()
    end_date = e3.get()
    basics = e4.get()
    # print variables and initialize Data
    init_data()

def init_data():
    print("Ticker: %s\nStart Date: %s\nEnd Date: %s\nBasis: %s" % (ticker, start_date,end_date,basics))
    global d
    d = Data(ticker, start_date, end_date, basics)

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="Ticker").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Start Date").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="End Date").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Basis").grid(row=3)

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e3 = tk.Entry(root)
e4 = tk.Entry(root)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text='get entries', command=get_args).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when running this I get;
ticker = e1.get()
NameError: name 'e1' is not defined

Comment: you run exactly the same code? because it works fine on my machine and `e1` is defined!

Comment: Oh I forgot to comment out some arbitrary code, works excellent, thank you! Now my question is if you do not mind me is what do I pass to Data()? Data is the receiver of the arguments in the following way (ticker, start date, end date, basis). I'm I supposed to pass Data(do_something())?

Comment: worked like magic, thank you so much for taking your precious time to help, highly appreciate it! Excellent solution!

Comment: Just for discussion if you have the opportunity I would like to ask why it is important to use global variables in this case?

Comment: @MisterButter. Its because of variables scope. Please watch [this](https://youtu.be/QVdf0LgmICw) video to find out more.

Comment: Thank you Masoud, have a nice weekend!